# XPath2 not found in Jasper-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm new to Rails but not to Java. I've been trying to test out the `jasper-rails` project at https://github.com/fortesinformatica/jasper-rails and that documentation makes it seem simple, but I have found it less so. And the developer hasn't responded to my issue, so I'm asking here.

I created my report with iReport (which `jasper-rails` implies works) and I put the .jrxml file in `app/views/jasper/index.jrxml`. When I load up `localhost:3000/jasper.pdf` I get this error:

```
  RuntimeError (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
   lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 16; Error at line 8 char 16: No query executer factory
  registered for the 'xpath2' language.): app/controllers/jasper_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

So it seems to not know what to do with `xpath2`. Unfortunately, the only option I have in the version of iReport is `xpath2`. If I scroll up in the Rails output I see:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 [....]
 Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory     registered for the 'xpath2' language.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1152)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.setQuery(JRDesignDataset.java:630)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setQuery(JasperDesign.java:791)
```

So it seems that JasperReports needs something configured for xpath2.

I've replaced the jars that `jasper-rails` uses with the jars in `ireport/modules/ext` but I got the same response. So, somehow, I have to tell `jasper-rails` about my `xpath2`. But how? Or would an older version of iReport work better? Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 0):

JasperRails works with xpath not with xPath2